# Parse multipart/form-data using JavaScript npm

Tags: javascript, npm, multipartform-data

I have a bunch of json files in a multipart/form-data format. I need to parse the files inside and store them as separate files using a js script (NPM)

Can anyone give me some advice on how to achieve this?

below an example of the json files:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2023-04-28T18:54:32.204432Z",
    "user_agent": {
        "original": "Jersey/2.31 (HttpUrlConnection 1.8.0_121)"
    },
    "host": {
        "ip": "172.20.10.2"
    },
    "message": "--Boundary_66_15756658_1682708071578\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"123.json\"; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n{\"firmware\":{\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"ENABLED\":false,\"SEQUENCE\":1,\"METHOD\":417}\n\r\n--Boundary_66_15756658_1682708071578\r\nContent-Type: multipart/form-data\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"123.json\"; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n{\"firmware\":{\"version\":\"1.0.0\"},\"ENABLED\":false,\"SEQUENCE\":1,\"METHOD\":417}",
    "http": {
        "request": {
            "body": {
                "bytes": "1195069"
            },
            "mime_type": "multipart/form-data;boundary=Boundary_66_15756658_1682708071578"
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "version": "HTTP/1.1"
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!